# Issue with external application.properties on Windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar

I have a spring-boot jar file that I run on both Windows and Linux. Now, I want to pass in a custom application.properties file for this.

This works perfectly fine on Linux, but on Windows, for some reason, it does not pick up the external application.properties file even though it is in the same folder as the jar file. (I know this because there is a server that I have configured to something in the jar itself, but in the external properties file, I am pointing to a server running on localhost. When I run the jar it is trying to connect to the server configured in the jar)

I then tried passing a custom config file. Did not work. Based on some suggestion in some forum, I passed the external app properties as:

`java -jar myApp.jar --spring.config.location=file:///c/jar-path/application.properties`.

Now, it looks like it is picking up this properties file. But it still gives me an error:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.config' in value "${my.config}
```

I have defined this property as:

```
@Value("${my.config}") String myConfig
```

I have added @Autowired to the class.

And in the app properties file, it is defined as:

```
 my.config=true
```

What is surprising is that this works perfectly fine on Linux. Windows gives me the above error though. When I run this app from Eclipse on Windows, it runs perfectly fine too. But I see this error when run as a jar file. (Again only on windows not on Linux)

Any suggestions on what the issue could be? Is there anything different to be done for Windows platform vs Linux?

Thanks in advance...
Om

Comment: Just guessing here, but have you tried using ``\`` on windows paths instead of ``/``? And don't forget the colon ``:`` in ``C:``

Comment: try `--spring.config.location=file:c:\jar-path\application.properties`

Comment: Same issue with that also. It looks like it is able to read the external application.properties file. but it is not able to read that particular property for some reason only on Windows. Is able to read on Linux.